# Using accents with discord.py in a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

It's my first post here, I don't know if I'm doing it right, but I hope I'll find solutions.

I'm creating a discord bot for a French/English server, using BeautifulSoup to get translations from web pages. As you may know, there are accents in the french language, and apparently, discord.py doesn't appreciate at all accents in command's arguments. I get this error :

> discord.ext.commands.errors.**CommandInvokeError**: Command raised an
>   exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
>   '\xe9' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is the command :

```
@bot.command() 
async def ft(word: str):
    """ French to English. Usage : !ft [word]"""
    [...]
```

I tried to type `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
and `# coding: utf-8` 
at the start, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated, I made the biggest part of it, just this issue is blocking from finishing that bot.

Comment: I think giving a copyable example would be beneficial here, because I'm sure many SO users don't have any non-ASCII characters on their keyboards.

Comment: The error apparently relates to user input, not to a character in your Python script. The `coding:` comment only helps for the latter; but Python 3 accepts UTF-8 source files even without the comment anyway.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code which caused the error, ideally in the form of a [mcve]. Most likely the bot receives a byte string like `b'\xe9galit\xe9'` from the network, and you are failing to decode this into a Python string properly (try `b'\xe9galit\xe9'.decode('latin-1')` to obtain `'égalité'` where obviously I simply guessed your input *might* be Latin-1).